# Cache-miss: htaccess request laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, cpanel

i install laravel 5.5 in my server
it's work well in local host and in one of my servers
when i transfer it to another server it give me error

```
mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

and i get this error on my cpanel error

```
[Wed Aug 29 13:27:12.060112 2018] [cpanel:warn] [pid 24177:tid 140535283795712] mod_cpanel cpanel_open_htaccess(): Cache-miss: htaccess request for '/home/username/public_html/projectfolder/.htaccess'
[Wed Aug 29 13:27:12.060104 2018] [cpanel:warn] [pid 24177:tid 140535283795712] mod_cpanel cpanel_open_htaccess(): Caching htaccess request for '/home/username/public_html/.htaccess'
[Wed Aug 29 13:27:12.060093 2018] [cpanel:warn] [pid 24177:tid 140535283795712] mod_cpanel cpanel_open_htaccess(): Cache-miss: htaccess request for '/home/username/public_html/.htaccess'
[Wed Aug 29 13:27:12.059812 2018] [cpanel:warn] [pid 24177:tid 140535283795712] mod_cpanel cpanel_open_htaccess(): Cache-miss: htaccess request for '/home/username/.htaccess'
```

Comment: @Devon what is this ?, and what should i do

Comment: Is this in your web server error log?  I'm not familiar with that warning but it's probably not related to your 500 error.  Are there any errors in your laravel.log?

Comment: this in Cpanel error, nothing in laravel error log

Comment: solved by reupload new version of my project, i suggest this error happened from firebase library because i install this after upload old version